# Horizon captive core disk requirements and practice

Tags: horizon

Having installed and ran horizon with captive-core, it seems that memory consumption is stable (~ 4.5 G). The disk space is though increasing while transactions keep coming. Around 10G/day.

From my understanding, the captive-core doesn't fetch all the history before to run. Would that mean the older data can also be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Might be the answer to my own question. There is a [`HISTORY_RETENTION_COUNT`](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/run-api-server/running/#managing-storage-for-historical-data) setting that automatically removes the older data.